# Displaying multiple locations on a map

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

How can I take approximately 50 company names, and have their headquarters plotted on a map?

If that's not possible: Assuming I had the addresses, how could I plot all those addresses on a map?

What (kind of) software should I use?

Comment: Where is this map to be presented? (E.g. a website, brochure, etc.)

Comment: I don't need it printed if thats whatyou mean

Comment: But do you want it on a website? Or?

Comment: whichever...  I don't really care so long as I can see...

Comment: @wizlog If it's just to see it you can use this website: http://gmaps.kaeding.name/ not much options but will let you see multiple locations on google maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a basic knowledge of programming you can look at the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) and embed it into a website or write a sample app to do what you need.

Otherwise you can use [Goole Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/index.html) which allows you to map multiple locations on a map